# Using shortcode in HREF in content loaded via functions.PHP

Tags: php, html, shortcode

Wordpress | Advanced Custom Fields plugin

I created a new field in the editor where my colleagues can fill in a URL relevant to that specific page. This URL will be used in the button we load on every single job listing page. This button is created within the functions.php file:

```html
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    $content = "<h3>Title</h3><p>text</P>
    <a href='[acf field='afas_url']' target='_blank' rel='noopener'><button>Solliciteer Nu</button></a>";
```

The above is cut off at the *'afas_url'* part. So, I think it has something to do with the quotations marks and probably not even hard to fix, but as I'm just starting to figure things out I couldn't find the answer myself yet.

I hope it's a clear enough explanation :)

(And maybe it's not best practice to use functions.php but it was already like this)

Comment: This is currently just text, your shortcode does not even get parsed - you need to call `do_shortcode` for that. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that